# list searching to find exact matches using TCL lsearch

Tags: tcl

I have a list and need to search some strings in this list. My list is like following:

```
list1 = {slt0_reg_11.CK slt0_reg_11.Q slt0_reg_12.CK slt0_reg_12.Q}
```

I am trying to use lsearch to check if above list includes some strings or not. Strings are like:

```
string1 = {slt0_reg_1 slt0_reg_1}
```

I am doing the following to check this:

```
set listInd [lsearch -all -exact -nocase -regexp $list1 $string1]
```

This commands gives the indexes if list1 includes $string1 (This is what I want). However, problem is if I have a string like slt0_reg_1, the above command identifies the first two elements of the list (slt0_reg_11.CK slt0_reg_11.Q) because these covers the string I search.

How can I make exact search?

Comment: Remove `-regexp`; this is used for matching with regular expressions; and unless specified by the expression, a match is valid as long as any substring matches in a string.

Comment: Your question doesn't look quite right either. `string1` is a list too? `lsearch` may not work quite like you expect it to, if you think it looks for each string in `string1`.

Comment: @Jerry yes, it is a list too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you want to add in word-boundary constraints (`\y`) to your RE. (Don't use `-exact` and `-regexp` at the same time; only one of those modes can be used on any run because they change the comparison engine used.) A little care must be taken because we can't enclose the RE in braces as we want to do variable substitution within it.

```
set list1 {slt0_reg_11.CK slt0_reg_11.Q slt0_reg_12.CK slt0_reg_12.Q}

foreach str {slt0_reg_11 slt0_reg_1} {
    set matches [lsearch -all -regexp $list1 "\\y$str\\y"]
    puts "$str: $matches"
}
```

Prints:

```
slt0_reg_11: 0 1
slt0_reg_1:
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare your list for an exact match of the part before the dot against another list, you may be better off using `lmap`:

```
set index -1
set listInd [lmap str $list1 {
    incr index
    if {[lindex [split $str .] 0] ni $string1} continue
    set index
}]
```